# Org-mode: blocks incorrectly parsed as org-mode markup

Tags: org-mode, org-export

I noticed a really weird behavior related to `#+begin_xxx`/`#+end_xxx` block. It turns out that contents inside those blocks are parsed as org-mode markup. That is, inside a block:

- `*` at the beginning of a line is considered as a heading. A direct impact is that `org-global-cycle` fold/unfold incorrectly sectioning.
- `[[not a link]]` is considered as an org-mode link. Export to pdf (`org-latex-export-to-pdf`) the org file will raise the error `Unable to resolve link: "not a link"` as it would fail to resolve unexisting links.
- and probably more...

## MWE

`emacs-version = 26.3`

`org-version = 9.2.6`

```
* H1
** H2
#+begin_example
* Should not be rendered as a heading!
[[Should be avoided when exporting]]
#+end_example

#+begin_src c
* sp  = "Should not be rendered as a heading!"
// [[Should be avoided when exporting]]
#+end_src
```

### Issue: `org-cycle` (<kbd>Tab</kbd>)

[image: org-cycle-1]
[image: org-cycle-2]

### Issue: `org-global-cycle` (<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd>)

[image: org-global-cycle-1]
[image: org-global-cycle-2]
[image: org-global-cycle-3]

### Issue: `org-export-latex-to-pdf`

[image: org-export-latex-to-pdf]

## Related question

- [Emacs org-mode source block incorrectly parsed as a link in export (unable to resolve link)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56534995/emacs-org-mode-source-block-incorrectly-parsed-as-link-in-export-unable-to-reso)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You must escape such constructs in example blocks. The [Literal Examples](https://orgmode.org/manual/Literal-Examples.html#Literal-Examples) section of the manual states:

> There is one limitation, however. You must insert a comma right before lines starting with either ‘`*`’, ‘`,*`’, ‘`#+`’ or ‘`,#+`’, as those may be interpreted as outlines nodes or some other special syntax. Org transparently strips these additional commas whenever it accesses the contents of the block.

```
#+BEGIN_EXAMPLE
,* I am no real headline
#+END_EXAMPLE
```

And it turns out that escaping the "fake" headline also solves the link export problem. Try exporting this:

```
* H1
** H2
#+begin_example
,* Should not be rendered as a heading!
[[Should be avoided when exporting]]
#+end_example

#+begin_src c
,* sp  = "Should not be rendered as a heading!"
// [[Should be avoided when exporting]]
#+end_src
```